# karate and maven - launch chrome with active javascript

Tags: javascript, maven, google-chrome, karate

I'm working with karate and I want to test my "feature" file.
However, when Chrome is launched by maven, javascript is disabled on chrome. So I can’t test my results
`<noscript> <strong>We're sorry but this application doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong> </noscript>`

Do you have an idea to force maven to launch chrome with javascript enabled ?

Thank you ;)

I haven’t found a solution yet

Comment: is this a UI test, I'm sorry I'm not able to understand. maybe your system has some strict security settings. can your provide a sample to replicate (edit your question if needed)